# View site as a guest

Tags: joomla-3.x, global-configuration

When I click view site button in joomla, it opens a new tab with a login form that I enter my super user info and is show the home page. 
But I want to visit the site as a guest to test user registration and profile.

How can I delete the login page that appears when I click view site in joomla? I want it opens without that login form.

Comment: Do you have the site offline? If so, go to your Global Configuration in the Joomla backend and set **Site Offline** to **No**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you have your site offline, you will be required to login to view the site. You will be presented with a login form as shown here:

[image: Website Offline]

There was an extension created to get around this drawback called "[Offline](https://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/miscellaneous/offline/offline/)". This creates a secret key that, when added to the URL, prevents the need to login.

---

**Alternate:** If your server is running [Apache](https://www.apache.org/), you can create a [`.htpasswd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) file in the root of your site and leave the site "online." This will require you to enter a password before Joomla! ever loads.